# trasformation index array in value

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, integer

example value return:

```
array[1]=1

array[5]=5

array[12]=[1, 2]

array[85]=[8, 5]

array[7453]=[7, 4, 5, 3]

array[8987556322415]=[8, 9, 8, 7, 5, 5, 6, 3, 2, 2, 4, 1, 5]
```

Which is the best way to convert the index to an array with single decimal value (only one number for every index)

```
var array=[30];

function getVal(array){    
    for ( i=0; i<i.length; i++ ){
        ....
    } return array;
}  
getVal(array);
```

-> array [1] = 0

-> array [0] = 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast it to string, and since string is an array of char, you can manullay parse them back to numbers.

```
var index = 8987556322415;

var arr = index.toString().split("").map(char=>parseInt(char));

console.log(arr)//[8, 9, 8, 7, 5, 5, 6, 3, 2, 2, 4, 1, 5]
```

Here is a [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/sexucim/edit?js,console) for you